# Is there a way to create unique type Id at compile time in C++

Tags: c++11

I can create a unique type id the following way:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct TypeId
{
  static size_t value()
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&TypeId<T>::value);
  }
};


auto intType = TypeId<int>::value();
```

It works at runtime but is there a way to do it at compile time ?
I would like to use it in a switch statement like this:

```cpp
switch (typeId)
{
  case TypeId<int>::value():
    // do something
    break;

  case TypeId<double>::value():
    // do something
    break;

  case TypeId<MyClass>::value():
    // do something
    break;
}
```

The problem here is that I cannot convert a pointer to the size_t at compile time:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct TypeId
{
  static constexpr size_t value()
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&TypeId<T>::value);
  }
};

constexpr auto id = TypeId<int>::value();
```

The example above gives the following error:

```cpp
error: conversion from pointer type ‘size_t (*)() {aka long unsigned int (*)()}’ to arithmetic type ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ in a constant expression
   constexpr auto id = TypeId<int>::value();
```

**UPDATE**

I would like to understand why returning an address is fine in a constexpr but converting it to an int is not. The following code compiles (but I cannot use pointers in a switch statement):

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct TypeId
{
  static constexpr void* value()
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<void*>(&TypeId<T>::value);
  }
};

constexpr void* id = TypeId<int>::value();
std::cout << "id: " << id << std::endl;
```

Comment: No, in general there's no way to do this. You can try compile-time hashing of `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`, but of course there can be collisions. Not speaking of having to use user-facing macros (yikes).

Comment: And now for the fun part: are you trying to reimplement `std::visitor`? Don't ;)

Comment: @ n.m. No, I would like to pass type ids between my library and C# bindings.

Comment: So why non-constness of these things is preventing you from passing them to C#? Why do you need `case TypeId<int>::value()` for that?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you want to get compile-time type information, then use compile-time ways to do this. The right way to do this is with [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

```
if(std::is_same<int, T>::value) {
    // do something
} else if (std::is_same<double, T>::value) {
    // do something else
} // ...
```

This *can* cause certain problems. if you're using methods for specific types, like `std::string::length()` in your conditions, you'll have a compile error. There are ways to solve this:

1. Use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)
2. Use [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to create template specializations that are dependent on the type
3. If you have only pointer-type problems, you have to `reinterpret_cast` all your pointers to `T`

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way in C++ to *automatically* allocate a unique integer type id and make it availabe compile time.

This is why libraries that need it use manual type registration, e.g.:

```
template<class T> struct TypeId;

#define REGISTER_TYPE_ID(T, id_value) template<> struct TypeId<T> { static constexpr int id = id_value; };

REGISTER_TYPE_ID(bool,                1)
REGISTER_TYPE_ID(char,                2)
REGISTER_TYPE_ID(unsigned char,       3)
REGISTER_TYPE_ID(unsigned short,      4)
REGISTER_TYPE_ID(unsigned int,        5)
REGISTER_TYPE_ID(unsigned long,       6)
REGISTER_TYPE_ID(unsigned long long,  7)
REGISTER_TYPE_ID(signed char,         8)
REGISTER_TYPE_ID(signed short,        9)
REGISTER_TYPE_ID(signed int,         10)
REGISTER_TYPE_ID(signed long,        11)
REGISTER_TYPE_ID(signed long long,   12)
REGISTER_TYPE_ID(float,              13)
REGISTER_TYPE_ID(double,             14)
REGISTER_TYPE_ID(long double,        15)
```

Comment: So the missing link is the auto-increment at compile time :) ?

Comment: @AlexandreA. Try auto-infringement across shared libraries. `__COUNTER__` macro works in limited cases.